# Unable to detect cycle after bundling with stencil

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm creating a StencilJS web component that uses a MonacoEditor, and I'm having issues when using it in the prod bundle.

I've defined a custom language and a few other bits. Everything works fine on my dev environment, but when bundling and trying to use in Prod, I get this error:

> Error: UNABLE to detect cycle, dumping graph

Are there any reasons why this error would come up?

I could only see that this gets fired after `languages.onLanguage`, so I suspected it could be my custom language and removed it, but it still has the issue without it.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to share my setup.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was triggered due to an earlier error, cause by bundling the package as ES5. Solved it by using the ESM bundle.